# Hyper-V Machine cannot join domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a laptop which has Hyper-V installed.

I have two virtual machines, "ws12-dc", the domain controller (domain: idg.local), and ws12-sql12, the sql server 2012 machine.

When I try to join the domain on my second machine, it say's that "idg.local" cannot be found. I can ping the ws12-dc by it's ip address, but I cannot ping it using "ws12-dc", nor can I ping "idg.local".

I tried to do a `ipconfig /flushdns` then `ipconfig /registerdns`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the DC's IP address as DNS on ws12-sql12? Otherwise name resolution will not work..

This could be one of the reasons

Comment: I guess that could be the problem. My guess is that I should set a static IP address on the DC, and then add that IP address as DNS on my other machine?

Comment: Correct, static IP on the DC, and with that IP as DNS on the ws12-sql12 will solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: As Dominic said 99% of the time if your IP level networking is OK this is from DNS.